# Android Network and Progress Dialogs: Any Libs?

Tags: android

I created an app which uses many resources from my server and so i have much network communication. Until now i used `HTTPUrlConnection` for that together with an `AsyncTask` and `ProgressDialog`. The dialog i created is bound to the task so that it always will continue when you rotate the device and if you canel the progress dialog the task gets cancelled as well. it works fine.

Now i read many articles about network communication and everywhere it wasnt recommend to use `HTTPUrlConnection` since it is slow. So what to do instead? I tried to find libraries where it is easy to implement the same behaviour i have no with the progress dialog and asynctask but unfortunately i couldnt find one.

Is there a good library for post requests which are fast and can easily be included into a progress dialog? I want to have the full controll over it so when i rotate the device the dialog and the request should continue but when i cancel the dialog the request should also be cancelled.

Comment: Use volley, The best library for network operation

Comment: i tried that but after 2 days of work to try to build a progress dialog like i had it before i could not manage it with volley.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually depends on the kind of networking you want to perform. I would suggest Google's official library [Volley](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/volley/index.html), which provides a great way to handle callbacks, and configuration changes, but if your networking calls has media type data (Images, Sounds, etc...), you have to know that Volley is not well suited for that kind of networking. A better alternative could be [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) or [okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/), or both.

Comment: I tried volley. after 2 days i could not get a progress dialog working like i had it before with an async task.

Comment: That's because Volley works asynchronously, in order to keep your asynctask you can use Okhttp.